# What is the 'correct' way to build an embedded / inline form in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js

I'm wondering what the best way to build an *embedded* or *inline* form is in Ember.js. An example of this type of form would be the new tweet form on the Twitter timeline page, the comment form on a GitHub issue, or the answer form on this very site. Such a form has a few properties that make it desirable from a UX perspective, namely:

- content is shown alongside the form, allowing the user to easily reference other posts / comments / tweets.
- it encourages contributions by not requiring a user to navigate away from the page.

The obvious approach seems to be to use a `{{render}}` helper to encapsulate all the form's logic into a separate view and controller. But the issue I've run into with this approach is that there's no clear way to set the form's model.

Ideally the form would be backed by an `Ember.ObjectController` with a freshly created model as its content. However, the `{{render}}` helper delegates the task of providing a model object to this controller to its parent, which means that I need to replicate the logic of providing an empty model object to this view at every place I use it in my app.

So what's the best practice  concerning this scenario? Is it that the `{{render}}` helper the right approach and I'm just missing something obvious? Or is there a better approach I could be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in Ember, routes are used to get models in the right place. You could always create a new CommentController (or whatever model is used for the form), and in the route's `setupController`, find the right model and set it on that controller:

```
SomeRoute: {
  ...
  setupController: function() {
    ... // normal setup for this route, possible this._super()
    this.controllerFor('comment', this.store.find('comment', 1));
  }
}
```

(untested pseudocode)